How to set events on <PresentationControls> React three fiber drei plugin?
I have code like this -
<Canvas
        gl={{
          preserveDrawingBuffer: false,
          antialias: true,
        }}
      >
        <PresentationControls
          polar={[-Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 2]}
          azimuth={[-Infinity, Infinity]}
        >
          <Stage
            preset={"portrait"}
            intensity={1}
            shadows={false}
            adjustCamera={1.2}
            environment={"forest"}
          >
           <SomeModel />
          </Stage>
        </PresentationControls>
</Canvas>

I want to track the rotation of the model using a state, but the PresentationControls does not have any onChange like events that I can use. How can I get the rotation values when the model is rotated using the PresentationControl?
I considered using Orbit Controls like -
 <OrbitControls
          onEnd={(e) => {
            setRotationX(eulerToDegree(e.target.object.rotation.x));
            setRotationY(eulerToDegree(e.target.object.rotation.y));
            setRotationZ(eulerToDegree(e.target.object.rotation.z));
          }}
        />

But Orbit Controls rotate the camera rather than the object, which is not what I want.
